# Optimize performance of custom pre-built option list to webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I am looking to add a pre-built options list, based on a query. I crafted the function nicely with the below code

```
function mitacan_webform_select_options_info() {
    $items = [];
    if (function_exists('basliklariAl')) {
        $items['addresses'] = array(
            'title' => 'Stok Kodları',
            'options callback' => 'basliklariAl'
        );
    }
    return $items;
}

function basliklariAl($component, $flat, $arguments) {
    $nodes = [];
    $select = db_select('node','n')
        ->fields('n',[
            'nid',
            'title'
        ])
        ->condition('type','urun')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
    foreach($select as $n) {
        $nodes[$n->nid] = $n->title;
    }
    return $nodes;
}
```

This is very slow, mostly because there are about 10k records. What can I do to optimise the process?

Comment: How often do you expect the query results to change ? Why don't you use cache_set and cache_get ?

Comment: I consume a web service to generate the nodes once a day, but expect the results to change rarely.

Answer (score 0):

You can always cache the results as seen in the [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/cache-api/cache-api-overview)

```
  if ($cache = cache_get('my_module_cache') && REQUEST_TIME < $cache->expire) {
    $data = $cache->data;
  }
  else {
    $data = 'xxxxxxx'; //do all your time taking complex calculations here
    cache_set('my_module_cache', $data, 'cache',  REQUEST_TIME  + (3600 * 24 * 30 * 6)); //stores in cache table and expires after 6 months
  }
```

More about [cache_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_set/7.x) and [cache_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_get/7.x)

Comment: I added the cache_set but the cache looks like 
`+---------------+------+--------+------------+------------+
| cid           | data | expire | created    | serialized |
+---------------+------+--------+------------+------------+
| mitacan_cache | N;   |  86400 | 1520589086 |          1 |
+---------------+------+--------+------------+------------+`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry the code was untested as I was just trying to give you a headstart ... I updated my answer with the official documentation example now that should probably work better ... but again its untested